# Can't boot up ubuntu 14.04 after upgraded from 12.04

Tags: 14.04, partial-upgrade

I have first installed Windows 7 ultimate, then I installed Ubuntu 12.04 through WUBI. Then after few days I have upgraded it to 14.04 and the whole upgradate process finished smoothly without any error.

Then the laptop was restarted and then it can't mount the directories. It displays the message like:

```
mount: mounting /dev/loop0 on /root failed: Invalid argument
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /roo/proct failed: No such file or directory`
`Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.

BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it is working very nicely. @Novice

Comment: @ArpitLangalia: don't thank anyone!  Just click the little grey check-mark below the "0" of the answer and for me, just follow [the 2 minute tour](http://askubuntu.com/tour)  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there may be an issue with your file system. Can you boot with a LiveCD and run a file system check [1].

This should help to point you in the right direction.

Best,

Lev

[1] https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilesystemTroubleshooting